# How to map ALT key in .vimrc?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, cygwin

In order to be able add blank lines without going into insertion mode, I'm trying to map `ALT-o` and `ALT-O` to `o<ESC>` and `o<ESC>`

I've tried the following in my `.vimrc`

```
map <M-o> o<ESC>
map <M-O> O<ESC>
```

and

```
map <ALT-o> o<ESC>
map <ALT-O> O<ESC>
```

and (as suggested below)

```
map <A-o> o<ESC>
map <A-O> O<ESC>
```

but none work. It just gives the usual behavior, as if `ALT-o` had not been defined.

This is my first time altering the `.vimrc` file, and I can't find where the documentation tells you how to designate the various keys. But I am able to verify that my `.vimrc` file is being read, by including:

```
map <Enter> ihello<ESC>
```

Which sucessfully maps `<Enter>` to inserting `hello` and returning to command mode.

I'm using vim with cygwin.

Comment: It sounds like your terminal isn't passing the alt sequences at all. Do any other known sequences work? What about trying Ctrl? What terminal are you using?

Comment: I'm using vim on cygwin, but I have made other scripts work, as my edit details.

Comment: Ctrl works, sort of. It doesn't seem to let me distinguish between `<C-o>` and `<C-O>`.

Comment: [Giles answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14765/how-to-map-alt-key-in-vimrc/14790#14790) is right on track. You should definitively switch to a more capable terminal. These problems should disappear and you'll get your keys back!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To see what your terminal is sending when you press a key, switch to insert mode, press `Ctrl+V`, then the key. Most keys with most terminals send an escape sequence where only the first character is a control character; `Ctrl+V` inserts the next character literally, so you get to insert the whole escape sequence that way.

Different terminals send different escape sequences for some key combinations. Many terminals send the same character (`^O`) for both `Ctrl+O` and `Ctrl+Shift+O`; if that's the case, Vim won't be able to distinguish between them.

You mention that you're using Cygwin; which terminal you're running Vim in is the most pertinent information. If you're using the native Windows console, get yourself a better terminal. I recommend [MinTTY](http://code.google.com/p/mintty/) for running Cygwin text mode applications in a terminal in Windows outside X, but Cygwin's Windows-native RXVT and [PuTTYcyg](http://code.google.com/p/puttycyg/) are also good. (Also [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) to run Windows console applications, but that's squarely off-topic here).

Answer (score 4):

If `Control+V` followed by `ALT-x` shows `^[x` (type in terminal) you can fix it with this small script from [vim.wikia.com](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Fix_meta-keys_that_break_out_of_Insert_mode):

```
for i in range(97,122)
  let c = nr2char(i)
  exec "map \e".c." <M-".c.">"
  exec "map! \e".c." <M-".c.">"
endfor
```

Add to .vimrc for all alt key mappings.

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind this and why this should work?

Comment: This changes the sequence that vim expects to the one that is sent by the terminal. The loop changes it for all keys in that range (a-z).

Answer (score 1):

This works for me on Ubuntu 16.04 xfce terminal (and alacritty rust terminal)

Set ultisnip snippet trigger to `Meta-/` (just like emacs snippet)

`let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="^[/"`

Here's now I type `^[/` in vim

In insert mode `Ctrl-V Alt-/`

(`Meta` is the `Alt` key on my PC keyboard)

Answer (score -1):

The M(eta) key is the windows-button. It is just `<A-o>`.

Comment: This also doesn't work.

Comment: This isn't always the case, on different keyboard layouts and language locales they are often different.

Comment: @Caleb is there any documentation for this?

Comment: I tried `map <A-o> o<ESC>` and it worked for me. If you put it in your `.vimrc`, did you reload it?

Comment: The asker already stated in their question that they verified the file was being loaded. This isn't relative to the user since they are on windows, but you can see different Meta/Win/Alt key configurations in the xkb geometry/symbol/keycode files. You will notice even in the gnome keyboard layout options there are several common ways to remap between Alt/Win/Meta. One of the reasons this exists is because of the disparity in base layouts.